# Continous liquid level measurement loop connection device

Tags: sensor, 4-20ma, level

I have 4-20mA loop device for measuring liquid levels. It was working well until I connected a motor (heavy load) to the same outlet(120Vac). I have this device ON and as soon as motor turns ON the output of the device starts flickering. I believe it is noise from the motor. How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Please improve your question by adding more details and using proper English. What is o/p? Have you considered buying a in-line noise filter from a hardware store?

Comment: @Sparky256, o/p is a very common term indeed for 'output'. i/p is 'input'.

Comment: @TonyM. Thanks for the info, but we try not to abbreviate here if possible. Some contractions are used, but for the most part we try to stick to proper English due to the number of countries and languages on SE sites.

Comment: @Sparky256, yes I see, that's a fair enough reason. Errm...just before 'try not to abbreviate' you mention 'info'. What is 'info'? :-)

Comment: @TonyM. One moment...I need to find a translator...

Comment: Don't switch on the motor.

Comment: Actually I will have to consider motor being ON or OFF. it is industrial application.

Answer (score 1):

Motors are electrically noisy.

One possibility is that the electrical noise from the motor is being conducted to the 4-20 mA device of the power line, corrupting its signals.  That's frankly the fault of the power supply in the 4-20 mA device, indicating crappy design.  There is really no excuse for that since proper line-connected power supply design already assumes the line is noisy.

It would be interesting to know know which tank level guaging system you are using.  Is it a pressure cell, ultrasound, radar, level-sensing "tape", something else?  What manufacturer?  I have some familiarity with this business and might be able to provide more insight.

Another but more remote possibility is that the 4-20 mA device is getting corrupted from noise radiated by the motor.  There is still no excuse for that either.  Proper design of sensitive analog electronics includes minimizing susceptibility to external radiation.  There are limits of course.  You can't really expect proper operation when you're 10 feet in the air 100 feet from a multi-killowatt radio transmitter.  If radiated interference is the problem, then just separating the motor and 4-20 mA device will help.  Radiation power density descreases with the square of the distance from the transmitter.

Of course this is all assuming that the 120 VAC outlet can supply enough power to run the motor and anything else connected to it.  Measure the voltage with the motor on and off.  If the voltage goes below 100 V, then that's the problem.  In that case, the 4-20 mA device is not at fault since you're feeding it power out of (the assumed) spec.

Comment: It is a two wire continuous level sensing device. should I look to add some king of filter in the circuitry.

Comment: @kc83: "two wire continuous level sensing device" doesn't narrow it down much.  That could still be a pressure cell, level-sensing tape, or even a float actuating a variable resistor.  What company? What product?

Comment: Float actuating variable resistor. I work with solution with innovation, CT. It was designed by one engineer, who is not with us anymore and I am trying to troubleshoot.

Comment: Olin did you get chance to look into this?